# Do solutions for complicated problems ripe during long breaks?

Tags: io-psychology, problem-solving, creativity

I often solve complicated problems by thinking about the problem for maybe 15 minutes, then taking a break for one or two hours, and then think for another 15 minutes. This often leads to much better solutions than working on the problem for 2 or 3 hours straight.

This is particularly evident for problems that have both an analytical and a creative part. It somehow seems that the solution matures or ripes unconsciously during the break.

Two questions to this:

- First of all, is this hypothesis that the solution somehow "ripes" unconsciously true/plausible? Or is it rather caused by the refreshed brain after the break?
- Second, does this phenomenon have a name under which more literature could be found?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [How is it that taking a break from a problem sometimes allows you to figure out the answer?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1/7001)

Comment: Duplicate, absolutely :-)

Comment: A question to this: Should we delete or keep duplicate questions? (Maybe keep because they offer a rewording of the original question that might help to find it by search engines.)

Comment: @Michael Keep, for exactly the reason you say (and not just search engines per se, but also for when people search within the site itself). https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates The main purpose of closing questions as duplicates (in my view) is to not repeat the answering effort; this is solved by having all those questions point to one place with answers. There is no penalty for asking a duplicate.